# grails 2.5 not displaying "UTF-8" chars in "show" pages, but shows correct chars in "edit". Grails is using the wrong charset

Tags: grails, utf-8

We have just noticed that all the UTF 8 chars, such as £ and € come out as "?" in our grails app, but only on specific pages.  We checked the DB (mysql 5.6), and they are definitely the correct UTF-8 char, e.g. doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM currency c
WHERE LENGTH(c.prefix) <> CHAR_LENGTH(c.prefix)
```

Returns the currency row with £ and € as the prefix (but not the rows which had normal chars as the prefix

The problem happens with both tomcat on Linux, and running from within Intellij 14 on windows 8.

Using chrome dev tools, the crux seems to be the offending pages are having a response header of:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

where as most pages have the correct response header of:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
```

All our "show", "index" and "list" pages are having ISO-8859-1, and all our "edit" gsp pages are having the correct UTF-8.

However, when we look at the GPS and the controllers, the code is identical.

If we do a global search on the project for ISO-8859-1 we only find entries for sitemesh in the web.xml. We dont know if this is relevant.

As there is literally no difference between a GSP which works, and one which doesn't, nor is there any difference in the controller methods, we are at a loss to know how to fix what grails is using as the charset of its response headers.

The pure scaffolded pages (empty controller) have the exact same problem - show has wrong char set and shows UTF-8 chars as "?", but edit works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add this to every controller:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    response.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8' 
}
```

Apparently this was fixed in grails 2.5.1

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11830